# Unable to start a MySQL Container & attach it to the Docker network

Tags: mysql, docker

I am following [Docker Labs](https://github.com/docker/getting-started) tutorial & have made it to the 7th step. Where I need to Attach MySQL DB container to my app network container. Upon entering the following command on windows 10 CMD:

```
docker run -d \
--network todo-app --network-alias mysql \
-v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
mysql:5.7
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Ajmal .M\getting-started>docker run -d \
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

C:\Users\Ajmal .M\getting-started>    --network todo-app --network-alias mysql \
'--network' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ajmal .M\getting-started>    -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
'-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ajmal .M\getting-started>    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
'-e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ajmal .M\getting-started>    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
'-e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Ajmal .M\getting-started>    mysql:5.7
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

[CMD Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYaoy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because it's trying to run each line as an individual command instead of one docker command.

On windows instead of `\` for a new line use `^`

```sh
docker run -d ^
--network todo-app --network-alias mysql ^
-v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql ^
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret ^
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos ^
mysql:5.7
```

The command above is the same as this one line command:

```
docker run -d --network todo-app --network-alias mysql -v todo-mysql data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos mysql:5.7
```